# sql Query to find different record in a column

Tags: sql, db2

I have table with 5 OR 6 COLUMNS and I need to use the below 2 columns to get the result

```
col1     col2

Acc1      USD
ACC1      GBP
ACC1      EUR
ACC2      USD
```

Result:

I need to find out if a acc has more than 2 currency, but the base currency is USD. I need to find out those records which has USD plus other currency if I have only USD accounts then it should not come in my result.

Answer (score 1):

With the information provided this could be an answer:

```
SELECT col1
  FROM tab
 GROUP BY col1
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Comment: much more elegant than mine...and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but should do the job.

```
with cte as 
  (
    SELECT t1.[col1],t1.[col2],(select count(t2.col1) from accounts t2 where t2.col1=t1.col1) as AllCurrency
    from accounts t1
  ) 
SELECT distinct cte.col1 from cte where cte.AllCurrency>1
```